# SQL where use both AND OR

Tags: sql

I have the problem to retrieve the query with statement AND OR

```
SELECT *
FROM [DPPLBMS].[dbo].[STUDENTS_DETAILS]
where AttendingConvocation='0' and (grade = 'A') or (grade='B') or (Grade='C')
```

Im trying the view the data with Attending Convocation = 0 and grade is A, B & C only.

The result is show both records, Attending Convocation show records 0 = Not Attend and 1 = Attend Convocation

Comment: Use parenthesis around the ors since you want to combine them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM [DPPLBMS].[dbo].[STUDENTS_DETAILS]
where AttendingConvocation='0' and (grade = 'A' or grade='B' or Grade='C')
```

Or even better maybe:

```
SELECT * FROM [DPPLBMS].[dbo].[STUDENTS_DETAILS]
where AttendingConvocation='0' and grade in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```